# Change terminal title running neovim as appimage

Tags: vim, terminal, neovim

According to [the docs](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/tag/v0.4.2) you can install and run neovim as an appimage using:

```
$ ~/nvim.appimage
```

This works fine, but leaves the terminal with a confusing title:
[image: Confusing terminal title]

I like the method of using an appimage, but can I create an alias which will allow me to type `vim` and get the neovim appimage and a terminal window title of "*neovim*"?

I have Oh My Zsh running on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Wouldn't you just be able to rename the appimage file to `neovim`, then for your zsh setup just include an `alias -g vim='~/neovim'`?

Comment: @Das_Geek Sounds sensible. Can anyone think of a reason _not_ to do this?